# Which actions are taken in compile time?

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-optimization

I cannot get the list of things that are optimized at compile time, and what are the compiler optimizations that do the reduction if all the necessary info is given. However, the question is tagged C, but the thing that made me ask it is C++'s constexpr - I naively thought that the things the keyword allows were already available "out of box".

EDIT: the basic example is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 8;
    printf("Answer is %d", a-b);
}
```

If compiled with -O0 (x86-64 GCC9.2) we get real load and subtraction when the program is run

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, 16
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 10
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 8
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
sub     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
mov     esi, eax
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
mov     eax, 0
call    printf
nop
leave
ret
```

When -O3 (x86-64 GCC9.2) is used, subtraction is optimized out and we load only 2

```
mov     esi, 2
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
xor     eax, eax
jmp     printf
```

We probably can replace some function calls with constant values or simplify functions if values are available in code. What is the optimization name that does the thing?

EDIT2 The question is mainly about GCC or Clang for x86-64 platform. I understand that a compiler must not optimize any code, but often programmers use the compilers with options other than -O0. As noted by KamilCuk, the code above can be reduced to `puts("Answer is 2")` but it is not, and I don't know why. I'd highly appreciate if someone provides an [or a link to] overview of optimizations that GCC or Clang do at different levels of optimization.

Comment: Compiler is allowed to not optimize the code at all and execute everything at runtime. Does this answer your question? (There is preprocessor, which has to be run before compilation, dunno if that counts.) There is no `constexpr` keyword in C. I don't understand the "already available out of the box" statement.

Comment: Edited the question. I'm interested in what compiler does with -O2/O3 settings and what is correct name for function call replacement with constant values, when it is or it is not done. Is there a thing other than possible aliasing that can stop such a optimization?

Comment: There is no notion of "compile time" in the C language. There are also no "compiler" nor "optimisation". These all exist in the realm of implementations.

Comment: Then this is way-way-way too broad. You seem to be asking specifically about a compiler which takes `-O2/O3` settings. Any abstract compiler is allowed __not to__ optimize the code at all. If you are asking if a specific compiler with a specific version with specific compiler options will optimize specific code, please, well, specify the compiler, version, options, source code and target architecture. `If compiled with -O0` - which compiler, which compiler version? `When -O3` - same. `void main(void)` is very wrong. For the code presented, the compiler just could generate `puts("Answer is 2")`

Comment: Edited the question trying to make it more precise. I cannot specify a code of interest, since a need an overview. `void main(void)` is a bad habit of me, for some combinations of MCUs and compiler it is recommended way to write.

Comment: `overview of optimizations that GCC and clang` So doesn't https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html and https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#optimization-level answer your question? `What is the optimization name that does the thing?` It's [constant propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

Comment: Thank you for the links, could you please recommend an article that tells how they work, like [How LLVM Optimizes a Function](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1603). There are books like "Engineering: A Compiler" but I hope there is an article on what and how is already done in Clang/GCC